# spring tool suite : missing dependencies after upgrading to spring boot 1.4.0

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, spring-tool-suite, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have upgraded spring boot version from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0 to be able to use @MockBean annotation to mock my beans in unit testing, but since I still have "The import **cannot be resolved to a type** compilation" error allover my projects, however I have updated the maven project dependencies from eclipse and deleted the repository folder from the file system and allowed maven to re download it but in vain.

btw, I can clean and install the project from command line maven command "mvn clean install".

Any ideas please?

---

Edit

I have changed spring cloud dependency version from Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT to Brixton.SR5 and this solves the problem with the cloud imports and @EnableDiscoveryClient annotation, but I still have problems with the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have the following errors

```
1-CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1 -> org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1: ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:pom:2.2.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 1-repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:pom:2.2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): timeout

2-Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)

Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): timeout

3-org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): timeout
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

The error messages seem to indicate that it's a timeout problem, however all other jars and dependencies are downloaded , my internet connection is very good and I have manged to build from maven command line without compile errors.

Comment: Could you provide the exact import that fails?

Comment: please check the original post reedit.

Comment: did you try to do a "Maven -> Update Project..." and check the "Force Download of Snapshot/Releases"? That helps in many of those cases.

Comment: I have a parent maven project with pom file contains the common dependencies and properties and so on...by explicitly changing anything in this file(even if a dummy thing) and save eclipse has rebuild the workspace and all compiler errors in markers are gone away.

Comment: @MartinLippert I will consider use this flag next time having such as problem....thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just based on a personal experience :)

I have a parent maven project with pom file contains the common dependencies and properties and so on...by explicitly changing anything in this file(even if a dummy thing) and save eclipse has rebuild the workspace and all compiler errors in markers are gone away.